# how to iterate over this example

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have this variable "data" that is array of objects:

```
[{"id_questao":1,"id_tipoquestao":1,"conteudo":"Pergunta exemplo 1","id_formulario":1},{"id_questao":2,"id_tipoquestao":1,"conteudo":"Pergunta exemplo 2","id_formulario":1}]
```

I want to iterate over "data" and get the `id_questao` , `id_tipoquestao` and `conteudo` out of the objects, whats the correct way of doing so.

Comment: Can you post the code containing your declaration of this `data` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.forEach` and `Object destructuring`

```js
var arr = [{"id_questao":1,"id_tipoquestao":1,"conteudo":"Pergunta exemplo 1","id_formulario":1},{"id_questao":2,"id_tipoquestao":1,"conteudo":"Pergunta exemplo 2","id_formulario":1}];

arr.forEach(({id_questao, id_tipoquestao, conteudo})=>{
  console.log(id_questao+" "+id_tipoquestao+ " "+conteudo);
});
```

`

Comment: It gives me: Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Comment: is data an array of objects? Because i have made snippet using the same data which you have posted. And it works fine

Comment: when i do console.log(data) it shows me exacly [{"id_questao":1,"id_tipoquestao":1,"conteudo":"Pergunta exemplo 1","id_formulario":1},{"id_questao":2,"id_tipoquestao":1,"conteudo":"Pergunta exemplo 2","id_formulario":1}] so i think it is

Comment: $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '../readform',
            data: {
                ajaxid: id,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data );

                var txt = "";

                for (var key in row) {
        if (row.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(key + " : " + row[key]);
        }
    }

Comment: i think i understood the problem, i used json.stringify on the data maybe thats the problem.. how do i "unstrigify"  it

Comment: JSON.parse(data)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `map()`, 
for example your array called arr which equals to what you mentioned.

```
   var newArr = arr.map(item => {item.id_questao, item.id_tipoquestao, item.conteudo})
```

now `newArr` contains these values from each index of `arr`.